# Как сделать плавное обновление времени в скрипте

Tags: javascript

```
var date = new Date();

var options = {
  era: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  weekday: 'long',
  timezone: 'UTC',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric'
};

function clock() {
  document.getElementById("doc_time").innerHTML = date.toLocaleString() ;
}
```

Comment: почитайте про `setInterval`

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под словом "плавное"?

Answer (score 1):

Функция `setInterval()` позволяет выполнять заданную функцию каждые n милисекунд

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  document.getElementById("doc_time").innerHTML = date.toLocaleString();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="doc_time"></div>
```